# Reactjs URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this loadfile function that loads an image after uploading.. I want to convert to get its URL path... but im receiving an error "URL.createObjectURL is not a function" but when i console the e.target.files[0], I can view the file in console.. can any one help me?

```
 loadFile: function(e){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any database storages like Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 2):

This most definitely is unrelated to react.  The reason you're likely experiencing this is the createObjectURL is still a part of a working draft and has not yet been finalized, and as such you won't have much browser compatibility.  See the below compatibility chart to see if your browser supports the feature:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility